# Tyk.io - Attempted administrative access with invalid or missing key

Tags: authentication, api-gateway, tyk

We are using the community version of Tyk. When trying to add new API via file-based add, and then reloading - it doesn't seem to work! It produces this in logs.

```
tyk-gateway_1  | time="Jun 21 04:56:28" level=warning msg="Attempted administrative access with invalid or missing key!" prefix=main
```

When I execute this…

```
curl -H "x-tyk-authorization: '352d20ee67be67f6340b4c0605b044b7'" -s http://localhost:8080/tyk/reload/group | python3 -mjson.tool
```

I am 100% sure the docker-compose took secret listed in tyk.standalone.conf file. I even logged into the container created and checked “tyk.conf” and it has this very secret. Not sure what is wrong at this stage. It just doesn’t seem to recognize it as an admin key. Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

Please check whether docker-compose.yaml file has the environment variable **TYK_GW_SECRET** set. If so, please use that value as secret as the environment variable takes precedence over the config values.

Please refer to https://tyk.io/docs/tyk-environment-variables/ for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the single quote covering the secret value.

Please try with below command and let us know.

curl -H "x-tyk-authorization: 352d20ee67be67f6340b4c0605b044b7" -s http://localhost:8080/tyk/reload/group | python3 -mjson.tool

Comment: Thank you! Yup tried that too but it doesn't seem to do it. I am also seeing this in the logs...

`tyk-gateway_1  | time="Jun 28 05:13:12" level=warning msg="Reconnecting storage: Redis is either down or ws not configured" prefix=pub-sub"`

Comment: This is the log I got so far as soon as I start it up - https://mclo.gs/3YNof7a

Comment: Please share tyk.conf file and docker compose file

Comment: Those are both the default files straight from Git repo which I cloned

Comment: `root@support-tyk-api-gateway:~# curl localhost:8080/hello
{"status":"pass","version":"v3.2.1","description":"Tyk GW","details":{"redis":{"status":"pass","componentType":"datastore","time":"2021-06-29T02:23:36Z"}}}`

Comment: tyk.conf file - paste.ofcode.org/M5CjPcvBxPGTiFqwKXw5Tv | Dockerfile - paste.ofcode.org/BrbrkmXAaXDadZQxDRxahz